# Using Group by with a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

```
     cities         people   lastupdate
    mumbai@c.com    2314     12/2/2014
    mumbai@c.com    1356     13/7/2014
    mumbai@c.com    1124     13/9/2014
    delhi@c.com     1778      1/1/2015
    delhi@c.com     2259      1/1/2014
```

i have three columns as `cities`, `people` , `lastdate`..i want the data as

```
mumbai@c.com|3|1/1/2015
```

ie. 1 column should be distinct, 2nd column should be count related to first and third column should give last update date.so my main problem is doing order by using the last update value ..

Comment: Why is `1/1/2015` associated with `mumbai@c.com`? Shouldn't it be `13/9/2014`?

Comment: sorry it should be 13/9/1015

Comment: Don't tell me, fix the question.

Comment: but i want to order it according to lastupdate..

Comment: There is no 13/9/1015, there's only 13/9/2014. Please fix the question to show the actual results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cities, COUNT(*), MAX(lastupdate) lastupdate
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY cities
ORDER BY lastupdate
```

`GROUP BY` gets the distinct `cities`. `COUNT(*)` will count the rows in that group, and `MAX(lastupdate)` will get the latest `lastupdate` for each city.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Query :

```
SELECT cities, COUNT(cities), MAX(lastupdate)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY cities
order by lastupdate
```

For Output refer: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a9a2/5)

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a9a2/6)

Comment: but i want to order it according to lastupdate and doing so it i have add it to group by and it returns multiple cities  again